# Confused on solving $\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\sqrt{{π\over 2}-\arctan{1\over (x-1)^2}}}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> Calculate $$\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\sqrt{{π\over 2}-\arctan{1\over (x-1)^2}}}$$

Those ones are most of the times tricky limits. Well: $\arctan=\tan^{-1}$, also $\arctan(1)={π \over 4}$. At first, I thought of making them similar fractions by using  the denominator $(x-1)^2$.. That option leads to nowhere.

Comment: Possible suggestion: what happens to $\arctan{y}$ as $y$ gets small?

Comment: Just to give you a figure: Draw a rectangle triangle of legs $1$ and $(x-1)^2$ so you have drawn  $\alpha=\arctan\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$. Then $\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\alpha=\beta\to 0\Rightarrow \sqrt {\beta}\to 0$.

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Note that by [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

$$\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\sqrt{{π\over 2}-\arctan{1\over (x-1)^2}}}=\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\sqrt{\arctan (x-1)^2}}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to make any simplification at all. Simply recognize that

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \arctan t = \pi/2$$

and that $1/(x - 1)^2 \to \infty$ as $x \to 1$. Hence, the limit is zero.

Comment: +1, long time no see.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x\to 1\implies \frac {1}{(x-1)^2} \to \infty \implies$$
$$ \arctan \frac {1}{(x-1)^2} \to \pi /2 \implies$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\sqrt{{π\over 2}-\arctan{1\over (x-1)^2}}}=0$$